# Can PowerShell tell the difference between on how its executed? (Scheduled Tasks -vs- Console)

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

Pertaining to PowerShell profiles, and storing command history to a file:

In my `profile.ps1` I have:

```
if ($Host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost')
{
    Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { Get-History | Export-Clixml $HistoryFilePath } | Out-Null
}
```

to save my commands to a file.

However, any scheduled task I have that calls PowerShell, it stores the executed command in that history file.  I am hoping to change the `if` statement to something smarter.

Comment: Is the `PSReadline` module not saving your command history already?

Comment: It did not seem to be doing that, no.  Should that be invoked automatically, or placed into the Profile.ps1?
Is it shareable between standard PowerShell and the ISE?
And where is the command history written out to?

Comment: The `PSReadline` module only works with the console version (not ISE) and is installed and active by default on Windows 10 (it can be installed as a standalone module on older Windows OS versions). The history file is at `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is restricted to your profile, correct?  So use a different account to run powershell scheduled tasks, the default is to use the system account, if you didn't change the user to your account for any tasks you should be good to go without the If statement.

Comment: Yes, restricted to my profile.  Your recommendation would complicate the issue, because they are my PS scripts that running under my creds to do work on my files/dirs.  So it then becomes an issue of changing NTFS permissions and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is probably to check whether the current host implements the [`IHostSupportsInteractiveSession`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bd6fdae73520931f0d27a29d6290e18761772141/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/MshHost.cs#L306) interface:

```
if($host -is [System.Management.Automation.Host.IHostSupportsInteractiveSession])
{
    Register-EngineEvent ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not look like that worked.  I updated the Profile.ps1 and then re-ran the scheduled task, and the history file was updated with the task command.